# Applying pre-defined filter on the looped files

Tags: arrays, bash, if-statement

I have some bash looping script which loops the files and do some things with them

```
for pdb in ${output}/*.pdb ; do
name=$(basename "$pdb")
echo "I am sending ${name} to some place!"
done
```

now I would like to introduce some filter within the loop to pass the files only without some keywords in any part of the $name , thus excluding all files which has the defined keywords.

For the realization I would like to set all keywords in an array

```
#For a file with that keywords within the name the script should stop and loop another file etc
declare -a keywords=('apo' 'Apo' 'APO' 'sauf');

#workflow for a signle keyword "apo"
 for traj in ${all_trr}/*.xtc; do
 traj_name3=${traj##*/[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].}
 if [[ "$traj_name" != *apo* ]]
 then
#begins loop from the another file
  echo "I am sending ${traj_name} to analysis"
  #break 
 else
  echo "I am not sending ${traj_name} to analysis"
  continue
 fi
done
```

So I need to adapt this work-flow for an array: 1) to compare each file name with the array element and 3) send it to the script only if it does not match it.
E.g I have files with a complex name where keywords appear in different parts:

```
08_29_2017.gromacs_AT1_dry_sauf.1rep.step7_1.pdb
08_29_2017.gromacs_AT1_dry_Apo.1rep.step7_1.pdb
08_29_2017.gromacs_AT1_wat_apo.3rep.step7_1.pdb
08_30_2017.gromacs_AT1_wat_Na.2rep.step7_1.pdb
```

So only

```
08_30_2017.gromacs_AT1_wat_Na.2rep.step7_1.pdb
```

should pass to the

```
echo "I am sending ${name} to some place!"
```

at the same time if i have the files only with the one keyword e.g apo

```
08_29_2017.gromacs_AT1_dry_apo.1rep.step7_1.pdb
08_29_2017.gromacs_AT1_dry_apo.1rep.step7_1.pdb
08_29_2017.gromacs_AT1_wat_apo.3rep.step7_1.pdb
08_30_2017.gromacs_AT1_wat_Na.2rep.step7_1.pdb
```

also only the last file should be processed (but the array should consist of many 10-15 keywords including 'apo')

Comment: As you know how to do this for one single keyword, what prevents you from looping over all elements of your array?

Comment: I have tried to intriduce abother loop outside this loop - to loop an array elements and compare it with the file name (and break the loop in case of matching) but it did not very accurate. So I would be grateful for the example

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I do not understand with your existing code:

1. Your pattern substitution `traj_name3=${traj##*/[0-9]...}` seems useless. Did I miss something? I will suppress it.
2. You assign a variable named `traj_name3` but you later use a variable named `traj_name`. Typo?
3. You show `*.pdb` filename examples but your code looks for `*.xtc`. Typo? I will assume it is `*.pdb`.
4. You do not give a clear pattern for your file names. I will assume that you want to skip a file if **any** of your keywords matches **anywhere** in the filename.

This being fixed, something like the following should work:

```
declare -a keywords=('apo' 'Apo' 'APO' 'sauf');
for traj in ${all_trr}/*.pdb; do
    for keyword in "${keywords[@]}"; do
        if [[ "$traj" == *$keyword* ]]; then
            echo "I am not sending $traj to analysis"
            continue 2 # continue outermost loop
        fi
    done
    echo "I am sending $traj to analysis"
done
```